# Saving data to models in Django with ForeignKey relationship

Tags: python, django

When I am parsing a page I can't save category and topic to DB in Django. What should I do?

```
class Category(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=60, unique=True)

class Topic(models.Model):
    topic = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=60, unique=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Page(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

I wrote it, but it doesn't work. Most likely add() cannot be used with models.ForeignKey, right? If yes, how to do?

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify

...

page = {
    'datetime': datetime,
    'title':title,
    'slug':slug,
    'short_text':short_text,
    'text':text,
    'image':image_name,
    'img_source':img_source,
    'page_source':page_source,
}

try:
    page = Page.objects.create(**page)
except Exception as e:
    print(e, type(e))


category = {'category':category, 'slug':slugify(category)}
category, created = Topic.objects.get_or_create(**category)
page.category.add(category)

topic = {'topic':topic, 'slug':slugify(topic)}
topic, created = Topic.objects.get_or_create(**topic)
page.topic.add(topic)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is a (non-null) `ForeignKey`, the field `topic` and `category` should refer to *exactly* one `Topic` and `Category` object.

Therefore you should *first* construct the `Category` and `Topic` object, and then create a `Page` that uses these objects, like:

```
category, created = Category.objects.get_or_create(
    category=category_name,
    slug=slugify(category_name)
)
topic, created =Topic.objects.get_or_create(
    topic=topic_name,
    slug=slugify(topic_name),
    category=category
)
page = Page.objects.create(
    datetime=datetime,
    title=title,
    slug=slug,
    short_text=short_text,
    text=text,
    image=image_name,
    img_source=img_source,
    page_source=page_source,
    category=category,
    topic=topic
)
```

I would furthermore advice to use `category_name` and `topic_name` over `category` and `topic` when you construct your `Category` and `Topic` objects, since otherwise, you introduce confusion.

Comment: `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: news_topic.category_id` what's wrong?

Comment: @AleksandrLozko: you likely did *not* add `category=category` in your `Page.objects.create(..)` (the last three lines).

Comment: Added all as you said.

Comment: @AleksandrLozko: hold on, your `Topic` has a `ForeignKey` to a `Category` as well, so you need to add a category object there as well.

Comment: `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object` But what happen now? It's connect with topic.

Comment: @AleksandrLozko: likely some of your variables (likely `datetime` is not a string, etc., but the `datetime` module). Please validate the data you aim to enter into your object.